# First sci-fi TV or film to use real world advertising of related products to bring those products into the canon of the universe

Tags: history-of

*Ghostbusters: Frozen Empire*, includes a news report within the film that describes the history of the Ghostbusters.

This news report users two items of real world footage about Ghostbusters related products to tie these elements into the film universe.

The first is from an advert for the Kenner Toys, *The Real Ghostbusters Proton Pack and Ghost Popper*, from the mid 1980's.

The second is a clip from the Ray Parker Jr, Ghostbusters Music Video, specifically the scene around the 3:24 mark where Ray and the Ghostbusters are walking through Times Square.

Seeing this scene led me to ask the question:

What is the first film or TV series that uses footage from adverts/music videos of it's own products to add said products into the shared universe of the film or TV show?